# Add a virtual namespace for a Python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-wheel

I have a python package with the following directory structure:

```
my_package/
    my_subpackage/
        __init__.py
        my_module.py
    __init__.py
    setup.py
```

When I generate the Python wheel and pip install it, I am not going to have the `my_package` namespace, so `my_subpackage` is going to be part of the global namespace of my `virtualenv` or whatever.

I know that the solution here is to create another directory called `my_package` and put everything inside it:

```
my_package/
    my_package/
        my_subpackage/
            __init__.py
            my_module.py
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

But let's say that I cannot change the directory structure for some reason. Is there a way to add a virtual `my_package` namespace in `setup.py` with the first layout?

Comment: can you add files under my_package? Should my_package contain anything else besides my_subpackage?

Comment: A full list of meta-data that `setup.py` accepts is available in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#additional-meta-data). It doesn't look like there's anything to specify a 'virtual' package name.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the [package_dir](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages) option in your `setup.py`.

Something like this should work:

```
setup(
    ...
    package_dir={'': '..'},
    packages=['my_package']
    ...
)
```

I never used relative paths with `package_dir`  though, so your confirmation would be appreciated.